# Wiring a light socket that doesn't have screws

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I'm having some trouble wiring a ceramic light socket. I've done this before for with the kind that you just screw the wires into ([the ones that look like this](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=_YRFW_KkJ5ev0PEPycGr2Aw&q=ceramic%20light%20socket%20wiring&oq=ceramic%20light%20socket%20wiring&gs_l=img.3..0i24k1.15315.18114.0.18439.9.4.1.4.4.0.152.572.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.9.588...0i30k1j0i5i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.kwYQS77q2G4#imgrc=Q2pgb_LBBvTWMM:)), but this one is different. Here's a picture

[image]

And another one with some of the text on the socket (one side is labeled white as well but I didn't bother editing this into the picture)

[image]

I've found numerous videos and descriptions of how to do the kind with screws, but none of this type

How do I wire this?

Comment: I would just buy a new light fixture. Those "back-stab" connectors are notorious for failing.

Comment: agree with @JonathonReinhart - no point messing around with this, doesn't look safe never mind easy.

Comment: Googled backstab, now I know why I haven't seen them before, not always a good practice to use them. Will be buying some new ones...

Answer (score 2):

If there is only 1 set of wiring coming to this fixture use the back stabs (I hate back stabs). If there are more than 1 set pigtail and then use back stabs. This is one of the few places I have used backstab fixtures. I would never use the back stabs to jumper the sets, if the pigtail is used the only power being used is by the fixture itself. I have not had any problems with pigtails and back stabs but using the fixture as the jumper I have seen hundreds of failures. There should be a strip guide on the fixture strip the wire to that length. Push the wire into the round hole . this can normally only be used with 14 awg wire. If no strip gauge strip between 1/2 to 3/4 inch if copper is showing a piece of scrap wire or a small screwdriver can be used in the slot to remove the wire and trim it off and verify that no copper is showing and you should be good to go.